# How to upgrade all packages only installed from experimental?

Tags: linux, debian, aptitude

I am using Linux Mint Debian Edition and am using the unstable for all my packages. I do have some that I installed from experimental like gnome3. How do I upgrade all and only all that have been installed from experimental to their new versions in experimental?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
apt-get install apt-show-versions
apt-show-versions -i
apt-get install `apt-show-versions -u -b | fgrep experimental`
```

See the man page for apt-show-versions.  There is an example with proper syntax using backticks.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to tell us a bit about what this code actually does and how it works? Thanks.

Comment: It may be best to do `apt-show-versions -u -b | fgrep experimental | xargs apt-get install`, just in case there are enough packages from experimental for command-line length to be an issue.  Better to mention it five years late than never, right?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is correct so its best to test this with `--simulate` first.

```
aptitude upgrade "?upgradable ?archive(experimental)"
```

Or the shorthand version.

```
aptitude upgrade "~U ~Aexperimental"
```